# JavaScript Titanium App int assignment

Tags: javascript, int, titanium-mobile

I'm working in JavaScript with Titanium for mobile app development. I'm having a problem down in the for loop with the bn int count. button[bn].setTitle('*') will always be 5 on all buttons created in the event handler, or if I uncomment //bn = 0;, which is outside of the for loop, it will update all buttons to be value zero.

In my mind, it should be assigning the value to each button,event handler, etc at the time of creation and not going back and changing it as it moves the count forward. What am I missing here or need to do different?

```
/**
 * create a view object to hold the buttons
 * and add the buttons into the view
 */
function createRatingButtons(numButtons,BarTitle,topspace) {
    // set vars
    var bn=0;
    var left = 5;
    var top =   5;
    /*
     * create a view for the buttons
     */
    var ratingView = Titanium.UI.createView({
        height:     100,
        color:      'white',
        top:        topspace,
    });

    /*
     * create a label to put into the view
     */
    var ratingLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
                text:                           BarTitle,
                color:                      '#fff',
                backgroundColor:    'transparent',
                textAlign:              'left',
                height:                     'auto',
                width:                      'auto',
                top:                            0,
                left:                           left,       
    })
    ratingView.add(ratingLabel);
    /*
     * do the for loop and add
     * the buttons to the view
     */
        var button = [];
    for(bn==0;bn<numButtons;bn++) {
                    button[bn] = Titanium.UI.createButton({
                title:              bn,
                width:              50,
                height:             50,
                color:              "black",
                // backgroundColor:    "blue",
                left:               left,
                top:                                top+ratingLabel.getHeight(),
            });
            /*
             * Add event handler for this button
             */
            button[bn].addEventListener('click', function(e)
                        {
                            Ti.API.info("Rating Button Click #: " + bn);
                            /*
                             * Update buttons below this count for this object
                             * to have colored stars, and all starts after this
                             * to be uncolored.
                             */
                            button[bn].setTitle('*')
                        });


            ratingView.add(button[bn]);
            left = left + 50 + 5;
    }
    //bn = 0;

  // return the entire block for this view  
    return ratingView;
}
```

Comment: Example of call method `scrollView.add(createRatingButtons(5,"test1",0));
scrollView.add(createRatingButtons(5,"test2",95));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function createRatingButtons(numButtons, BarTitle, topspace) {
    // set vars
    var bn   = 0;
    var left = 5;
    var top  = 5;

    // create a view for the buttons
    var ratingView = Titanium.UI.createView({
        height: 100,
        color:  'white',
        top:    topspace,
    });

    // create a label to put into the view
    var ratingLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        text:            BarTitle,
        color:           '#fff',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        textAlign:       'left',
        height:          'auto',
        width:           'auto',
        top:             0,
        left:            20
    });
    ratingView.add(ratingLabel);

    // add the buttons to the view
    var button = [];

    for(bn = 0; bn < numButtons; bn++) {
        button[bn] = Titanium.UI.createButton({
            title:  bn,
            width:  50,
            height: 50,
            color:  "black",
            left:   left,
            top:    top+ratingLabel.getHeight()
        });

        // add event handler for buttons
        button[bn].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            Ti.API.info("Rating Button Click #: " + e.source.title);

            /*
             * Update buttons below this count for this object
             * to have colored stars, and all starts after this
             * to be uncolored.
             */
            e.source.setTitle('*');
        });

        ratingView.add(button[bn]);
        left = left + 50 + 5;
    }

    // return the entire block for this view  
    return ratingView;
}


scrollView.add(createRatingButtons(5, "test1", 0)); 
scrollView.add(createRatingButtons(5, "test2", 95));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you are trying to access bn inside the anonymous function. the value
   of bn will be evaluated when the anonymous function gets executes. at
   that time the value of bn will be the 1 less then the value of
   numButtons variable.

   So avoid using bn inside the anonymous function. you can use
   e.source to get the reference to the button.
2. also, i think you are by mistake using

> ==

in you for loop.

```
for(bn==0;bn<numButtons;bn++)
```